# How to create an array from single table data with parent and child included?

Tags: php

I have data in a table something like in this image. In this example, 87 is the main parent which have child category `92, 97, 100`. Each child can also have sub categories.

[image: Data]

This is my code so far I have tried, but I am not able implement level 3 of the array.

```
    public function getList(int $id): array
{
    $finalArray = [];

    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['parent_id'] === '87') {
            $finalArray[$value['id']] = [
                'title' => $value['title'],
                'subCategory' => []
            ];
            continue;
        }
        // Extract parent
        $parentId = $value['parent_id'];
        if ($this->multiKeyExists($finalArray, $parentId)) {
            $finalArray[$parentId]['subCategory'] = [
                'title' => $value['title'],
                'subCategory' => []
            ];
        }
    }
}

protected function multiKeyExists(array $arr, $key)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
        return true;
    }
    foreach ($arr as $element) {
        if (is_array($element) && $this->multiKeyExists($element, $key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Expected result:

```
- 92
  - 93
     - 95
  -96
```

[image]

Can anyone help me with a simple way to solve the problem ?

Comment: You could simply do a recursive function

Comment: Can you show how the final array should look like?

Comment: @RafaelMora I have added more information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortResult($result,$id=87){
   $finalArr=[];
   $finalArr['id']=$id;
    foreach($result as $key=>$val){
        if($val['id']==$id){
            $finalArr['title']=$val['title'];
        }
        if($val['parent_id']==$id){
            $finalArr['subs'][$val['id']]=sortResult($result,$val['id']);
        }
    }
    return $finalArr;
}
```

Comment: thanks but in your case too id = 95 is missing. It is a sub component of 93

Comment: Idk but t should work for unlimited levels recursively

Answer (score 0):

The recursive function will look for a child and run itself

```
$createtree = function ($start = NULL) use ($result,&$createtree){
    $start = $start ?? 0;
    $part = $result[$start];
    //has childs?
    if($key = array_keys(array_column($result, 'parent_id'),$part['id'] )){
         $part['sub'] = array_map(function($val) use ($result,&$createtree) { 
             return $createtree($val);
             },$key);
         
    }
    return $part;
   
    
};
print_r($createtree());
```

Edit: working sample
https://onlinephp.io/c/1c7dd

Comment: No it didn't worked as expected.

Comment: @user1687891 are you sure you implemented it correcyl? and if so what didnt it do correctly?

Comment: Inside `93` there are sub-components 95 and so on.